# Using Hosting env in Dbcontext

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

Is there a way I can use hosting env variable to decide which seed data to load? I DI Ihostingenvironment in Dbcontext but doesnt work. Is there any other way? 
One way I think is by looking into connectionstring and manually checking if dev/QA exists but thought if there is a better way to do it?

Comment: you can always DI a singleton

Comment: even in the Dbcontext? I think I will try now!

Comment: yes, thats how i usually do it. DbContext is also a service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a separate class to use as a singleton.

```
public class DbOptions
{
    public bool UseDefaultSeed { get; set; }
}
```

In your services add it as:

```
if (env.EnvironmentName == "")
    services.AddSingleton(new DbOptions {
        UseDefaultSeed = true
    });
```

You can now inject `DbOptions` in your DbContext.